# Is there a way to add an inbox for institutional email account to the Start Menu?

Tags: email, pin-to-start

I have added an email account to my Windows phone which connects to my institutional email inbox. It is not Gmail, YMail, or Outlook so there are no apps already so I can add the app to Start for convenient access. Is there a way other than linking the mail account to Outlook inbox to add the inbox for this new email account to the Start Menu?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Email inboxes show up in the app list. So you can simply find your inbox there, long-press (press and hold) on it until a context menu pops up, then select "pin to start".